# Where are the official tkinter docs or github repository?

Tags: python, tkinter, documentation

The closest to official docs I've found is this:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

But, I can't find details on classes like `tkinter.Entry`, which has an argument `validatecmd`. Where can I find documents or the original code, that detail all of the arguments `validatecmd` takes. I'm not interested in an explanation on `validatecmd`, since its an example of many similar questions I've had. I'm also not interested in a 3rd party tutorial, since they don't cover ALL of the arguments a function can take, and sometimes the obscure ones can be helpful.

Comment: Since I beat you up a little I'll be "nice". That link that you posted ... click it. You see smack dab in the middle of the top of the page where it says: "source code: Lib/tkinter/__init__.py"? Click that. Et Voila ~ imagine that! They even posted the github link at the top of the docs you are looking for. 

Comment: Oh whoops that's embarrassing, guess that's what I get for skimming through google search results

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is a python wrapper around a tcl/tk interpreter. The canonical documentation for Tk are the [Tcl/Tk man pages](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/contents.htm).

These manual pages are the definitive reference of all of the widgets, functions, options, and behavior of tk. The documentation is written for Tcl programmers, but it's a very easy mental transformation to apply the documentation for python. For more information see the [Tkinter Life Preserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-life-preserver) section of the official python documentation.

For a good third-party tutorial, see the [tkdocs.com tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html).